# assign value at specific list index in robot framework

Tags: variables, robotframework

I have a list:

```
@{IFUP}  10  20
```

I want to modify only one of those values, e.g:

```
${IFUP}[${idx}]=  Set Variable  30
```

where $idx is 0

This produces `No keyword with name ''${IFUP}[${idx}]='`. Same happens with direct `${IFUP}[0]` assignment.

RobotFramwork version is 3.1 (list syntax is a bit different).

I would be happy with a variable variable solution like: `${IFUP_${idx}}=` but this produces the same error.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **'Set List Value'** keyword from Collections library.

In your case, it should be

```
Set List Value  ${IFUP}    0    30
```

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Set%20List%20Value

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code:

```
List_at_place_change
    @{IFUP}    Create List    10    20
    Log    ${IFUP[0]}
    Set List Value    ${IFUP}    0    30
    Log    ${IFUP}
```

Comment: Hi, this just creates a new variable named "IFUP[0]" which is different from the original. If you use "Log   ${IFUP}" you will get the original values, 10 20.